# how get the same keyword in file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a list file

```
MFC_530_18MM_007_F0
MFC_520_18MM_008_F0
MFC_430_18MM_001_F1
MFC_270_18MM_002_F1
MFC_270_18MM_003_F1
MFC_720_18MM_004_F1
MFC_130_18MM_005_F1
MFC_540_18MM_006_F1
MFC_BT580_18MM_007_F1
MFC_530_18MM_008_F1
MFC_MP110_18MM_009_F1
MFC_AAC1_18MM_010_F1
```

I want to get the same name
ex:

```
MFC_530_18MM
MFC_520_18MM
MFC_430_18MM
MFC_270_18MM
MFC_270_18MM
MFC_720_18MM
MFC_130_18MM
MFC_540_18MM
MFC_BT580_18MM
MFC_530_18MM
MFC_MP110_18MM
MFC_AAC1_18MM
```

I have this code:

```
@echo off
set "R_Str_f=_0.*"
set "R_Str_fed="
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" source.txt') do (
        set "line=%%b"
          if defined line set "line=!line:%R_Str_f%=%R_Str_fed%!"
          echo(!line!
          )
    )> output.txt
```

I want this code to remove the last character and then remove duplicate keywords but it does not work

Comment: What is the specific problem? Note that "it does not work" is not an error description! Anyway, it seems that you try to use a wildcard `*` in the search string, which cannot be done. But it seems you always have the same number of underscores `_`, so you could simply use this: `for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3* delims=_ eol=_" %%A in ("source.txt") do echo(%%A_%%B_%%C`…

Answer (score 0):

not sure which OS you're using.
on Unix/Linux and SHELL you can try to use the "_" as a field separator (FS)

cat yourfile | awk 'FS="_" { print $1"_"$2"_"$3}'

Comment: The `cmd` tag description: "Command Prompt (executable name cmd.exe) is the Microsoft supplied command line interpreter on OS/2, Windows CE, and all Microsoft Windows operating systems."

Answer (score 0):

Given that your question intent appears to be to replace everything from and including `_0` with nothing, does this help?

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(   For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("source.txt") Do (
        Set "LineContent=%%G"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For /F UseBackQ^ EOL^=^|^ Delims^=^| %%H In (
            '!LineContent:_0^=^|!'
        ) Do EndLocal & Echo(%%H
    )
) 1>"output.txt"
```

*For the above example code to work, I have assumed, and therefore it is a requirement, that your initial strings do not include any `|` characters.*

---

If you are using Windows 10, and do not mind what order your output file list is in, then you could probably perform the entire task, i.e. with duplicates removed, like this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
(
    For /F UseBackQ^^^ Delims^^^=^^^ EOL^^^= %%G In ("source.txt") Do @(
        Set "LineContent=%%G"
        %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "Echo(%%LineContent:_0=&:%%"
    )
) | %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /Unique 1>"output.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to result in the first three (3) items separated by LOW LINE (underscore) characters, this might work.

```
@powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path '.\in.txt' | ForEach-Object {($_ -split '_')[0..2] -join '_'}"
```

Result:

```
PS C:\src\t\so68080140> .\doit.bat

MFC_530_18MM
MFC_520_18MM
MFC_430_18MM
MFC_270_18MM
MFC_270_18MM
MFC_720_18MM
MFC_130_18MM
MFC_540_18MM
MFC_BT580_18MM
MFC_530_18MM
MFC_MP110_18MM
MFC_AAC1_18MM
```